# Identifying messages posted by my app in Slack

Tags: slack-api

I'm developing a Slack app that posts alert apps to channels. I want this app to check the history of a channel to find messages it has posted earlier so it can respond accordingly. For example, if there's an alert that has not yet "cleared" it will update said alert instead of posting a new message.

The challenge I'm encountering is that it's not clear how I can identify messages that my app has posted. I see that I can search a channel with [conversations.history](https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.history), and that gives me message events. It looks like some messages have a `user` property. There are also `bot_message` sub-type messages that have a `bot_id` property. However, I don't see any way to identify my *app ID*.

Should every app have an associated `bot_id`? `user` ID? If so, where do I get these IDs so I can filter the conversation history?

**Update**

I tried calling the `bots.info` method with no bot ID parameter hoping it would give me *my* bot ID, but it returned no data other than an "OK" status.

Comment: brainstorming here, is creating a database a possibility? You could store and update this information and use queries to determine this information I believe

Comment: I still don't have the basics; how do I get my bot ID?

Comment: is updating the message a possibility? I believe I am seeing Slack documentation that messages could be updated. I cant actually read the docs currently due to a firewall issue. https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.update

Comment: Yes, they can be updated. My problem is finding the message to update. To find the message to update, I need to know which messages my bot posted. To find those, I need my bot ID.

Comment: Now you have your ```bot_id``` per discussion below sorry to keep jumping threads

Comment: The problem isn't getting the bot ID manually; it's getting it _programmatically_ or from an _authoritative source_.

Comment: Is it not constant? I'm under the impression it is

Comment: No idea if it's constant across installs/reinstalls or across multiple teams. Docs don't say. Admin page doesn't expose bot ID, only app ID.

Comment: Well if it is constant which we can test for, then that would be a step in the right direction.

Comment: Let me clarify; my goal isn't just to get my bot working. It's knowing the _correct_ way to do things without manually posting as the bot to get the bot ID so it can be used in code later on. There should be a way in the API to accomplish this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps because Slack has a long history of different APIs, I was misled. Apparently, it's possible for me to find messages my bot previously posted but not how I thought. Here were my misunderstandings and what I've found out when playing with the Slack API tester.

Using [`conversations.history`](https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.history), you can get a list of messages posted in a channel. The docs say that the history returns an array of [`message events`](https://api.slack.com/events/message), and that these have a subtype field. One of the subtypes is [`bot_message`](https://api.slack.com/events/message/bot_message), so my assumption is that messages posted by my bot would have this sub-type. The docs for `bot_message` has a `bot_id`, which I don't know for my app, and `username`, which I don't know what it will match.

However, it turns out when I posted a test message, that the message did *not* show up as a `bot_message`; rather it appears in the history *without a subtype* and has properties which don't seem to match any documentation:

```
{
  "bot_id": "B01HSBYRKUZ",
  "type": "message",
  "text": "Testing the Slack API; please ignore.",
  "user": "U01HDNUJ5EE",
  "ts": "1609878469.036400",
  "team": "<omitted>",
  "bot_profile": {
      "id": "B01HSBYRKUZ",
      "deleted": false,
      "name": "my-bot-name",
      "updated": 1608584973,
      "app_id": "<omitted>",
      "icons": {
          "image_36": "...",
          "image_48": "...",
          "image_72": "..."
      },
      "team_id": "<omitted>"
  }
}
```

So although it's risky to code against an undocumented format (or maybe I just can't find the right docs?), I can filter these messages by looking to see if there's a `bot_profile.app_id` that matches my app's ID, which I do know.

Comment: is the ```bot_id``` in this response not the correct one or something?

Comment: `bot_id` is fine, but bot ID isn't shown anywhere in the Slack app admin pages, so I didn't have it until posting a test message. I'm also not sure if `bot_id` will remain consistent like, say, if I need to install for another team or have to reinstall the app with new permissions.

Comment: If there was an API call to get your bot ID that would work fine, but as I posted in the question there doesn't seem to be any earthly way to know your bot ID programmatically

Answer (score -1):

you may know id your bot if use context. Example:  const {botUserId} = context